# Get host from uri that contains a scheme

Tags: c#, uri, url-scheme

my current problem is if i have a url like  "onenote:https://somerandomhost.com/foo1/foo2" the Host & Authority of my Uri obeject is always ""

my current soltions is:

```
var uri = new Uri(hyperlinkURL);
if(uri.Scheme != "https" && uri.Scheme != "http")
{
    uri = new Uri(uri.LocalPath);
}
```

is there some better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work:

```
    var link = "onenote:https://somerandomhost.com/foo1/foo2"; 
    var uri = new Uri(link);
    if(uri.Scheme != "https" && uri.Scheme != "http")
    {
        uri = new Uri(uri.LocalPath);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);
    Console.WriteLine(uri.Authority);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nLqXE4